# What is the color theme of the second example image in the vscode 1.39 release notes?

Tags: visual-studio-code

What is the name of this color theme?

[image: What is the name of this color theme?]

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found it! It's called the Github Sharp theme:

[Github Sharp Theme](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=joaomoreno.github-sharp-theme)